# Android Library Module developed in Kotlin exported to Java Application causing Failed resolution of: Lkotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I've developed an Android Library Module in Kotlin - tested it on a Kotlin project and it all works just fine. Using gradle's `maven-publishing` plugin, I've generated the `aar` files and uploaded them on a Maven Server, so latter I added the lib on a Android Java Application using `compile 'group:artifact:version'`.

Library files seems to be recognized, however, when I attempt to start an activity existent on the Lib I get the following stacktrace:

```
05-12 14:21:48.221 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev W/art: Unable to resolve Lbr/com/**********/dataform/renderengine/core/model/DataCollector; annotation class 182
05-12 14:21:48.222 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev W/art: Unable to resolve Lbr/com/**********/dataform/renderengine/core/model/DataCollector; annotation class 181
05-12 14:21:48.222 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev W/art: Unable to resolve Lbr/com/**********/dataform/renderengine/core/model/DataCollector; annotation class 181
05-12 14:21:48.223 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev W/art: Unable to resolve Lbr/com/**********/dataform/renderengine/core/model/Collect; annotation class 182
05-12 14:21:48.224 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev W/art: Unable to resolve Lbr/com/**********/dataform/renderengine/core/model/Collect; annotation class 180
05-12 14:21:48.224 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev W/art: Unable to resolve Lbr/com/**********/dataform/renderengine/core/model/Collect; annotation class 180
05-12 14:21:48.224 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev W/art: Unable to resolve Lbr/com/**********/dataform/renderengine/core/model/Collect; annotation class 179
05-12 14:21:48.225 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev W/art: Unable to resolve Lbr/com/**********/dataform/renderengine/core/model/Collect; annotation class 179
05-12 14:21:48.225 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev W/art: Unable to resolve Lbr/com/**********/dataform/renderengine/core/model/Collect; annotation class 180
05-12 14:21:48.225 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev W/art: Unable to resolve Lbr/com/**********/dataform/renderengine/core/model/Collect; annotation class 180
05-12 14:21:48.225 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev W/art: Unable to resolve Lbr/com/**********/dataform/renderengine/core/model/Collect; annotation class 179
05-12 14:21:48.226 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev W/art: Unable to resolve Lbr/com/**********/dataform/renderengine/core/model/Collect; annotation class 179
05-12 14:21:48.226 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev W/art: Unable to resolve Lbr/com/**********/dataform/renderengine/core/model/DataCollector; annotation class 180
05-12 14:21:48.227 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev W/art: Unable to resolve Lbr/com/**********/dataform/renderengine/core/model/DataCollector; annotation class 180
05-12 14:21:48.227 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev W/art: Unable to resolve Lbr/com/**********/dataform/renderengine/core/model/DataCollector; annotation class 179
05-12 14:21:48.227 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev W/art: Unable to resolve Lbr/com/**********/dataform/renderengine/core/model/DataCollector; annotation class 179
05-12 14:21:48.227 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev W/art: Unable to resolve Lbr/com/**********/dataform/renderengine/core/model/DataCollector; annotation class 180
05-12 14:21:48.228 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev W/art: Unable to resolve Lbr/com/**********/dataform/renderengine/core/model/DataCollector; annotation class 180
05-12 14:21:48.228 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev W/art: Unable to resolve Lbr/com/**********/dataform/renderengine/core/model/DataCollector; annotation class 179
05-12 14:21:48.228 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev W/art: Unable to resolve Lbr/com/**********/dataform/renderengine/core/model/DataCollector; annotation class 179
05-12 14:21:48.229 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev W/art: Unable to resolve Lbr/com/**********/dataform/renderengine/core/model/DataCollector; annotation class 179
05-12 14:21:48.229 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev W/art: Unable to resolve Lbr/com/**********/dataform/renderengine/core/model/DataCollector; annotation class 179
05-12 14:21:48.230 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev W/art: Unable to resolve Lbr/com/**********/dataform/renderengine/core/model/Feedback; annotation class 182
05-12 14:21:48.232 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev W/art: Unable to resolve Lbr/com/**********/dataform/renderengine/core/model/Feedback; annotation class 181
05-12 14:21:48.232 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev W/art: Unable to resolve Lbr/com/**********/dataform/renderengine/core/model/Feedback; annotation class 181
05-12 14:21:48.233 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev W/art: Unable to resolve Lbr/com/**********/dataform/renderengine/core/model/Entry; annotation class 182
05-12 14:21:48.233 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev W/art: Unable to resolve Lbr/com/**********/dataform/renderengine/core/model/Entry; annotation class 180
05-12 14:21:48.234 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev W/art: Unable to resolve Lbr/com/**********/dataform/renderengine/core/model/Entry; annotation class 180
05-12 14:21:48.234 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev W/art: Unable to resolve Lbr/com/**********/dataform/renderengine/core/model/Entry; annotation class 180
05-12 14:21:48.234 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev W/art: Unable to resolve Lbr/com/**********/dataform/renderengine/core/model/Entry; annotation class 180
05-12 14:21:48.235 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev W/art: Unable to resolve Lbr/com/**********/dataform/renderengine/core/model/Feedback; annotation class 179
05-12 14:21:48.235 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev W/art: Unable to resolve Lbr/com/**********/dataform/renderengine/core/model/Feedback; annotation class 179
05-12 14:21:48.272 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<br.com.**********.dataform.renderengine.presentation.feedback.PieChartFeedback>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/github/mikephil/charting/charts/PieChart;
05-12 14:21:48.273 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.Class.newInstance!() (Class.java:-2)
05-12 14:21:48.273 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev I/art:     at android.app.Activity android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.String, android.content.Intent) (Instrumentation.java:1078)
05-12 14:21:48.273 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev I/art:     at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2557)
05-12 14:21:48.273 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2726)
05-12 14:21:48.273 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
05-12 14:21:48.273 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1477)
05-12 14:21:48.273 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev I/art:     at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
05-12 14:21:48.273 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev I/art:     at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
05-12 14:21:48.273 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6119)
05-12 14:21:48.273 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
05-12 14:21:48.273 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:886)
05-12 14:21:48.273 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:776)
05-12 14:21:48.273 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev I/art: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/*****.*****.dev-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/*****.*****.dev-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/*****.*****.dev-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/*****.*****.dev-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/*****.*****.dev-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/*****.*****.dev-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/*****.*****.dev-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/*****.*****.dev-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/*****.*****.dev-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/*****.*****.dev-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/*****.*****.dev-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/*****.*****.dev-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/*****.*****.dev-2/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
05-12 14:21:48.273 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev I/art:     at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
05-12 14:21:48.273 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:380)
05-12 14:21:48.273 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
05-12 14:21:48.273 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.Class.newInstance!() (Class.java:-2)
05-12 14:21:48.273 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev I/art:     at android.app.Activity android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.String, android.content.Intent) (Instrumentation.java:1078)
05-12 14:21:48.273 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev I/art:     at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2557)
05-12 14:21:48.273 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2726)
05-12 14:21:48.273 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
05-12 14:21:48.273 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1477)
05-12 14:21:48.273 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev I/art:     at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
05-12 14:21:48.273 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev I/art:     at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
05-12 14:21:48.273 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6119)
05-12 14:21:48.273 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
05-12 14:21:48.273 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:886)
05-12 14:21:48.273 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:776)
05-12 14:21:48.275 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<br.com.**********.dataform.renderengine.presentation.FormActivity$assembleWizard$1>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lkotlin/jvm/internal/Lambda;
05-12 14:21:48.275 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.Class.newInstance!() (Class.java:-2)
05-12 14:21:48.275 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev I/art:     at android.app.Activity android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.String, android.content.Intent) (Instrumentation.java:1078)
05-12 14:21:48.275 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev I/art:     at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2557)
05-12 14:21:48.275 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2726)
05-12 14:21:48.275 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
05-12 14:21:48.276 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1477)
05-12 14:21:48.276 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev I/art:     at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
05-12 14:21:48.276 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev I/art:     at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
05-12 14:21:48.276 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6119)
05-12 14:21:48.276 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
05-12 14:21:48.276 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:886)
05-12 14:21:48.276 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:776)
05-12 14:21:48.276 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev I/art: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "kotlin.jvm.internal.Lambda" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/*****.*****.dev-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/*****.*****.dev-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/*****.*****.dev-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/*****.*****.dev-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/*****.*****.dev-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/*****.*****.dev-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/*****.*****.dev-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/*****.*****.dev-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/*****.*****.dev-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/*****.*****.dev-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/*****.*****.dev-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/*****.*****.dev-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/*****.*****.dev-2/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
05-12 14:21:48.276 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev I/art:     at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
05-12 14:21:48.276 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:380)
05-12 14:21:48.276 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
05-12 14:21:48.276 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.Class.newInstance!() (Class.java:-2)
05-12 14:21:48.276 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev I/art:     at android.app.Activity android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.String, android.content.Intent) (Instrumentation.java:1078)
05-12 14:21:48.276 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev I/art:     at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2557)
05-12 14:21:48.276 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2726)
05-12 14:21:48.276 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
05-12 14:21:48.276 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1477)
05-12 14:21:48.276 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev I/art:     at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
05-12 14:21:48.276 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev I/art:     at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
05-12 14:21:48.276 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6119)
05-12 14:21:48.276 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
05-12 14:21:48.276 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:886)
05-12 14:21:48.276 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:776)
05-12 14:21:48.482 11735-11735/*****.*****.dev E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                 Process: *****.*****.dev, PID: 11735
                                                                 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lkotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics;
                                                                     at br.com.**********.dataform.renderengine.presentation.FormActivity.assembleWizard(FormActivity.kt:117)
                                                                     at br.com.**********.dataform.renderengine.presentation.FormActivity.onCreate(FormActivity.kt:71)
                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/*****.*****.dev-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/*****.*****.dev-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/*****.*****.dev-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/*****.*****.dev-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/*****.*****.dev-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/*****.*****.dev-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/*****.*****.dev-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/*****.*****.dev-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/*****.*****.dev-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/*****.*****.dev-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/*****.*****.dev-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/*****.*****.dev-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/*****.*****.dev-2/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
                                                                     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
                                                                     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                                                                     at br.com.**********.dataform.renderengine.presentation.FormActivity.assembleWizard(FormActivity.kt:117) 
                                                                     at br.com.**********.dataform.renderengine.presentation.FormActivity.onCreate(FormActivity.kt:71) 
                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679) 
                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

This is my module's build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply from : 'publish.gradle'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName libVersion

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    // TEST
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    // GOOGLE
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$appcompat"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$appcompat"
    compile "com.android.support:design:$appcompat"

    // OTHER
    compile('org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.+') {
        exclude module: 'stax'
        exclude module: 'stax-api'
        exclude module: 'xpp3'
    }
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.2'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'

    // RX ANDROID
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.1'

    // KOTLIN
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"

    // ANKO
    compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-common:$anko_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-sdk15:$anko_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-support-v4:$anko_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-appcompat-v7:$anko_version"
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}
```

Comment: Is `kotlin-stdlib-jre7` supposed to work on Android? AFAIK, Android build tools currently support only Java 6 platform, so you can try to use `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version`, which is targeted for Java 6, and see if it works.

Comment: I've did the change and you saved my day. Thanks a lot! I'm having another problem though which is, module aar is being generated without its dependencies, therefore, I'm having to import they all on the application were I'm importing it. (Please submit an answer so I can accept it)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The `kotlin-stdlib-jre7` artifact is not supposed to work on Android, which currently supports only Java 6 platform. When targeting Android, you should use `kotlin-stdlib`, which is built for JRE 6:

```
// KOTLIN
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
```

Comment: I've similar gradle file with same exception, changing stdlib did not work for my case. What else can cause this exception?

Comment: @dgngulcan, what is `$kotlin_version` here?  I am getting this error when syncing my project `Could not get unknown property 'kotlin_version' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.`

Comment: @blueware it is the `kotlin` version as a property. you can define it in your root `build.gradle` file as `   `project.ext{ kotlin_version = '1.2.41' }`

Answer (score 8):

#### UPDATE 2020-21:

For anyone who still gets this error, it could rise up from the simple interaction of a compiled **AAR library which contains Kotlin sources** that interacts (for instance, parameters passing) with an already started android java project.

If this is your case, just **add Kotlin dependencies** in your build.gradle (the one who refers to the application) to add the language support necessary to use the library.

```
dependencies {

    //.....

    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:+"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

This could happen also using a Kotlin source file but, if you add a Kotlin source the Android Studio IDE has a good support that prompts you if you want to add Kotlin language support to your project, so it's more probably a problem that arises from an interaction with a third-party lib

Answer (score 0):

If you use libraries like Retrofit you must add this parameters to your build gradle file

```
android{
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
    }
}
```