# Android Library Module developed in Kotlin referred in Java Application getting : Lkotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics exception

Tags: java, android, maven, kotlin, aar

Hi I am developing Android library using kotlin. And developing the Android application using Java. And I am referring the kotlin android library (aar) in the java application.

Everything works fine when I add the kotlin aar as module dependency in the java application. But when I refer the same kotlin aar using local maven repo getting the following error

```
              java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lkotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics;
                  at com.test.mobileprotectlib.RootCheckUtils$Companion.isTestKeysExist(RootCheckUtils.kt:33)
                  at com.test.mobileprotectlib.RootCheckUtils$Companion.isDeviceTampered(RootCheckUtils.kt:17)
                  at com.test.mobileprotectlib.RootCheckUtils.isDeviceTampered(Unknown Source:2)
                  at com.test.appj.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
               Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.test.appj-4zcXF6xzE5sP-wb7eK-tzA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.test.appj-4zcXF6xzE5sP-wb7eK-tzA==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.test.appj-4zcXF6xzE5sP-wb7eK-tzA==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
                  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                  at com.test.mobileprotectlib.RootCheckUtils$Companion.isTestKeysExist(RootCheckUtils.kt:33) 
                  at com.test.mobileprotectlib.RootCheckUtils$Companion.isDeviceTampered(RootCheckUtils.kt:17) 
                  at com.test.mobileprotectlib.RootCheckUtils.isDeviceTampered(Unknown Source:2) 
                  at com.test.appj.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17) 
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975) 
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Following is the kotlin aar build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

project.ext {
    artifactId = 'mobilesecurity-core'
    groupId = 'com.test.mobilesecurity'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27



    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.0.1"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags ""
            }
        }

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
/*
    publishing {
        repositories {
            maven {
                url "../../../../.m2"
            }
        }
        publications {
            maven(MavenPublication) {
                groupId 'com.test.mobileprotect'
                artifactId 'mobileprotectLib'
                version '0.0.1'
            }
        }
    }*/

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "../../../../.m2"
        }
    }
    publications {
        aar(MavenPublication) {
            // Don't forget to change these
            setGroupId(project.groupId)
            setArtifactId(project.artifactId)
            version android.defaultConfig.versionName

            artifact(bundleRelease)
            pom.withXml {
                def dependenciesNode = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')
                configurations.compile.allDependencies.each {
                    if(it.group != null && (it.name != null || "unspecified".equals(it.name)) && it.version != null) {
                        def dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode('dependency')
                        dependencyNode.appendNode('groupId', it.group)
                        dependencyNode.appendNode('artifactId', it.name)
                        dependencyNode.appendNode('version', it.version)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I found a post with similar issue but couldn't figure out the issue in my setup

[Android Library Module developed in Kotlin exported to Java Application causing Failed resolution of: Lkotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43943474/android-library-module-developed-in-kotlin-exported-to-java-application-causing)

Any help will be really useful.

Thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it worked for me after I added the kotlin configuration in Android java application

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android' and     implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the standard library for the JVM:

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
```

Comment: I tried as you mentioned but no luck. On analysing I found that it is happening with specific function only. Which is as follows @JvmStatic fun isTestKeysExist() = android.os.Build.TAGS.contains("test-keys") . The above exception occurs when accessing this kotlin static function from Java application. It works fine when calling this function from kotlin application.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem on **Xamarin.Android** fixed by add reference NuGet Package: [Xamarin.Kotlin.StdLib](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Kotlin.StdLib/)