# How to solve Android 12 cannot use MqttAndroidClient

Tags: java, mqtt, paho, android-12

In my Android Studio, I would like to connect the Mqtt Android client to my laptop host (in the same machine). I make it similar to this guide

https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-client-library-enyclopedia-paho-android-service/

Then, I found that the Android 12 (API 32 in my case) may not support the `org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.1.1` dependency. So, I followed this solution below, by imported the `serviceLibrary-release.aar` library from github provided instead. (The problem appear in this link was the same of my case)

[Android paho mqtt crashes Android 12 - Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71155187/android-paho-mqtt-crashes-android-12-targeting-s-version-31-and-above-requi)

After that, I ran into another error.

```
error: constructor MqttAndroidClient in class MqttAndroidClient cannot be applied to given types;
                MqttAndroidClient client = new MqttAndroidClient(MainActivity.this, "tcp://10.0.2.2:1883", clientId);
                                           ^
  required: Context,String,String,Ack
  found: MainActivity,String,String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

So I'm not sure that the library from the solution above can be applied to my old code, or, do I need to modify some code?

Here is my code and the gradle file.

***repositories***

```
maven {
    url "https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-releases/"
}
```

***Dependencies***

```
implementation files('libs/serviceLibrary-release.aar')
implementation 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.2.5'
```

***Android Manifest*** (Added permission below)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

```
<service android:name="info.mqtt.android.service.MqttService"/>
```

***Main Activity***

```
import info.mqtt.android.service.MqttAndroidClient;
```

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button buttonConnect;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        buttonConnect = findViewById(R.id.buttonConnect);
        buttonConnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String clientId = MqttClient.generateClientId();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, clientId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                MqttAndroidClient client = new MqttAndroidClient(MainActivity.this, "tcp://10.0.2.2:1883", clientId);

                try {
                    IMqttToken token = client.connect();
                    token.setActionCallback(new IMqttActionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                            Log.d("Debug", "onSuccess");
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onSuccess", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                            Log.d("Debug", "onFailure");
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onFailure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            exception.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    });
                } catch (MqttException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The error appear in this line (when the button is clicked)

> MqttAndroidClient client = new MqttAndroidClient(MainActivity.this, "tcp://10.0.2.2:1883", clientId);

From the error message prompted above. I think that's because the constructor's parameter of this class require a type `Ack` also, but I have no idea on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From output you provided, it seems you only need to specify Ack as the last parameter of your constructor.
It's acknowledgment that you received a message. According to official [description](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/android-javadoc/org/eclipse/paho/android/service/MqttAndroidClient.Ack.html), there is two modes available.

First, `MqttAndroidClient.Ack.AUTO_ACK`, which acknowledge automatically as soon as you received a message.

And then you have `MqttAndroidClient.Ack.MANUAL_ACK`, which requires you to manually acknowledge by doing `MqttAndroidClient.acknowledgeMessage(String)`

You can test it simply by adding the auto for now, and if it's ok then you can manually acknowledge yourself with custom rules.

Comment: I changed it to `MqttAndroidClient client = new MqttAndroidClient(MainActivity.this, "tcp://10.0.2.2:1883", clientId, Ack.AUTO_ACK);`. I've got this error instead `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lkotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics;`

Not sure that do you mean like using Ack from paho or from my downloaded library? Because I'm using the downloaded one.

Comment: This error come from Kotlin, i think it's not related to MqttAndroidClient. see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43943474/android-library-module-developed-in-kotlin-exported-to-java-application-causing

Comment: I have no idea about that, maybe it comes from the library I got from this link 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71155187/android-paho-mqtt-crashes-android-12-targeting-s-version-31-and-above-requi'. I found that it is written in Kotlin, but I used it for my Java Android App. So I don't know where it gets an error by MqttAndroidClient line. For now, I'm thinking about downgrading my api to be around api version 30 to avoid the problem in paho if I can't figure it out.

Comment: also I wonder if I should use it for Kotlin application instead? Since the library is written in Kotlin.

Comment: Yeah app in Android and lib in Kotlin may cause similar problems, you should definitely use Kotlin for your app, or Java for both app and lib. 
You can take a look at HiveMq as an alternative to Paho, which is easier IMHO